# Facebook login not working after IP change on Server

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

After changing my IP address on Server, Facebook login is not working. 
So I reverted back previous IP but it is still not working anymore.

There is no response.
Seems that there is some IP protection 
How Can I delete FB cache or understand something more? :/

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You should probably be talking to your ISP

Comment: No I'm speaking of server Ip and I'm speaking of fb app that is no more working :(

Comment: If your app was working and you haven't changed it then this is not a programming issue. Even if you have changed your app there's insufficient information for us to help. [so] is not Facebook. If you've changed your server or Facebook configuration then you should be talking to Facebook or your ISP.

Comment: If programming facebook app is not programming ok. Otherwise I need an expert that have some idea how to find the problem. We used a service to hide our real Ip for hacker attack problems and now we cannot make fb app working even reverting previous setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's was a Facebook bug, the IP was blacklisted in the facebook app, but without reason.
And even it was inserted into whitelist it was blocked for some days.
Now solved.

- we inserted IP in whitelist
- we removed IP from whitelist
- we add both IPs in whitelist
- we created a new app for test
- we come back to previuos IP but nothing to do

"This IP can't make requests for that application"  this seems a bug  that other used had after changing IP.

At the end we used the previous IP to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your ISP, or your FB account is compromised.

Considering that by "changing your IP" and then "changing it back" implies you probably used a proxy, then most likely that proxy was not secure and a hacker stole your account and changed the password.

Try resetting by email. If your email is also no longer valid, then you know a hacker stole your account. Report this to Facebook.

p.s. this is not a programming questino and hence is off-topic. Perhaps try Superuser?

Comment: No I'm speaking of server Ip and I'm speaking of fb app that give no response back